# Hypernym of "pair/dyad", "tetrad", "pentad"

Tags: hypernyms

Does the English language have a hypernym for words like "pair", "triad", "tetrad", and "pentad"? I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: It could be a set.

Comment: I hope beyond hope that the answer is n-ads.

Comment: "Group".  There is no higher concept in the original set aside from the number of members.  Once you abstract that away, all you have is a collection.

Comment: Note that the first element in this sequence is ***not*** a *pair*, but a [dyad](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dyad). (Although this is orthogonal to the question of names for these things.)

Comment: *polyad* is the word used to define any number of relationships

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe these are all examples of **cardinal quantifiers**

> **cardinal numbers**, or cardinals for short, are a generalization of the natural numbers used to measure the cardinality (size) of sets. [[Wikipedia]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_number)
>
> **Quantifier:** (n) an expression that indicates the scope of a term to which it is attached. [OED]

So, given a pair, triad, tetrad, etc., each is defined by its cardinal attributes (2, 3, 4, n) along with an identifiable and consistent expression regarding the property of each number.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematicians and computer scientists
sometimes use the word [***tuple***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tuple)
or the construct [***n*-tuple**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) (e.g., *2-tuple*, *3-tuple*, etc.). 
(This is derived/generalized from words
like “double”, “triple”, “quadruple”, “quintuple” and “sextuple”.) 
This differs from *pair*, *triad*, etc., and the other suggestions
(*set*, *group*, *collection*, etc.)
in that *tuple* implies that order is significant. 
For example, [red, green, blue] is not the same 3-tuple as [blue, green, red].

I don’t know whether this would be understood
by somebody not in one of the above fields. 
(I’m not even sure how well it is known *within* those fields.)

Answer (score 0):

If I needed a name I would call such nouns "group names for numbers".

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to the same question.  The only thing I discovered was that beyond pentad, we have hexad, heptad, ogdoad, ennead and decad.  They are Greek cardinal prefixes but I could not find any collective term for them beyond this.  I suggest we invent the word 'cardinads'!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and your contribution might be better-suited as a comment than an answer. After participating on this site a little more, you will earn enough reputation points to leave comments (such as this one). In the meantime, I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to better familiarize yourself with our standards and guidelines.